# Raspberry PI Relay power motor

Tags: relay, motion, switches, dc-motor

Does anyone happen to have a similar example for a python code when pressing a button a relay is turned on which is powering a motor to open a gate for 5 seconds and then closes by giving a signal to another relay which is connected with opposite positive and negative to the motor to close the gate ( [image: Relay Diagram]  this picture shows how i an going to try and connect the motor and relays) would i also be possible to add motion detection so if there would be motion the second relay isn't powered so the gate wouldn't close

Thanks

Comment: I am sure that googling "python relay button" would give you a good starting place.....  Then if you get stuck on a specific problem, you can post your code and schematic and ask another question.

Comment: Nothing to do with the Pi.

Answer (score 2):

Your design has some shortcommings

- There is no direct 5V output
- the [3v3 probaply isn't strong enaugh](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66610/is-3v3-of-pi-enough-to-power-5v-relay) to drive a relay so you need a transistor too and a [diode to protect the Pi 5v](http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/raspberry-pi/simple-raspberry-pi-relay-control-over-the-internet/)
- the accumulated cost for the components exceed the price for a ready [L298 H-bridge module ($2.5-$3)](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2x-L298N-Dual-H-Bridge-DC-Stepper-Motor-Driver-Controller-Board-Module-Arduino/322838582612?_trkparms=aid%3D444000%26algo%3DSOI.DEFAULT%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D50544%26meid%3D256cda7b438c42bcbf3303eb341b4269%26pid%3D100752%26rk%3D5%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D231454411738%26itm%3D322838582612&_trksid=p2047675.c100752.m1982) for which [instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-L298N-Dual-H-Bridge-DC-Motor/) are available

Comment: Thank you LotPings for the response, yes i noticed that and just purchased 2 relays that work with 3.3v which come out of the GPIO. do you think i'll managed to make it work with these ? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/3-3V-5V-10A-Relay-Module-for-Arduino-Nano-Due-Raspberry-Pi-ESP8266-Optocoupler/272272819712?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Comment: Can't say anything about unknown components, If your specs are correct you  can only try and if it fails still better the design.

Comment: true i am going to try them out and see what happens, you wouldn't have a similar code as i'm new to this subject

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT TRY THE 3.3V realays with the rpi without a transistor. Switching a relay on requires quite a bit of current, and gpio pins can supply very little current(I think less than 8ma). if you try to operate a relay with a raspberry pi gpio pin, you will most likely break the gpio pin(and possibly other parts as well) on your pi. The solution is to use a transistor, as LotPings mentions. A transistor works by taking a very small current and using it to switch a much larger current. There is no way around using a transistor and diode to control a relay with the rpi, unless your relay is [a relay module](https://howchoo.com/g/m2qwmte5nzk/how-to-use-a-relay-with-a-raspberry-pi) with a transistor already built in. As for the code, use python's rpi.gpio library. It is really simple. To get you started, google [raspberry pi rpi.gpio hello world](https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry%20pi%20rpi.gpio%20hello%20world)

Hope this helps, and let me know if you have any questions!